# Implement Multiselect jquery plugin with two sides for MVC Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, multi-select

I'm trying to implement a JQuery plug-in called "Multiselect" with two sides which allows the user to select items from the left list box into the right list box. But when I try to implement it with MVC Web API, it fails :-(

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the "to" array parameter is empty. The "id" parameter is coming over just fine (because it's part of the URI).  Here is the jquery:

```
 $("body").on("click", "#post-multi", function () {
    var btn = $("#post-multi");
    var src = btn.attr("post-src");
    var formMethod = btn.attr("post-method");
    var rec = $("#multiselect_to>option").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        url: src,
        method: formMethod,
        data: rec,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            bootbox.alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the HTML for the "right" list box containing the user selected choices:

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
        <select name="to[]" id="multiselect_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the `rec` variable's value before request?

Comment: rec: mnu_about,mnu_cntct,mnu_faq,mnu_home,mnu_svc,mnu_login

Comment: I expect ONLY the values of the options as described in the rec variable. I don't need to have their "labels" with it.  So I'm expecting a simple array of values that I can add to the permissions table.

Comment: Try `data: { to: rec },`

Comment: Nope. Same result :-(

Comment: Even when I hard-code the rec variable with a string and change the API parameter from string[] to string it won't work! I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer spares someone out there the many hours of frustration I spent figuring this out. This issue is about knowing the difference between sending COMPLEX types and SIMPLE types to the server.  In most of my development I use "complex" types (I send data that is serialized into a View Model or Data Transfer Object). In this rare occasion I'm sending a "simple" type (a single data type parameter of type string, integer, or bool; in my case, an array of strings).

Web API handles "simple" in much the same way as "complex" types except for a couple of tweaks that must be made:

1) Include [FromBody] in front of your "simple" type parameter in your Web API function (the name of the parameter is IRRELEVANT. You can name this anything you want; it doesn't have to match the name of your selector):

```
public IHttpActionResult AlterPerms(int id, [FromBody] string[] to)
        {
            . . .
        }
```

2) Change your Ajax call to send an empty data parameter: data: { '': rec }  So the whole code in my case looks like this:

Web API:

```
        //api/perms/3
        [Route("api/perms/{id}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AlterPerms(int id, [FromBody] string[] to)
        {
            permSvc.AlterPermissions(id, to);
            permSvc.Save();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

JQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", "#post-multi", function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    var src = btn.attr("post-src");
    var formMethod = btn.attr("post-method");
    var rec = $("#multiselect_to>option").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).toArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: src,
        method: formMethod,
        data: { '': rec },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response, status, xhr) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            bootbox.alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```